# Acredito que certas funcionalidades não deveriam ter reputação

Tags: debate, reputação

Eu fiz uma pergunta, no dia seguinte encontrei a reposta e não posso responder minha própria pergunta porque não tenho reputação, ou seja, vou deixar de ajudar outras pessoas devido à minha falta de reputação.
Eu sou nova nessa área de programação, então não tenho como ajudar ainda.

Acredito que certas funcionalidades não deveriam ter reputação.

Ainda não entendi o porque ter reputação pra tudo.

O que vocês acham?

Comment: Tem certeza que é por falta de pontos? Não seria por outra razão? (pergunta fechada, por exemplo). Se for o segundo caso, primeiro precisa resolver o problema da pergunta, para eventual reabertura.

Comment: "Ainda não entendi o porque ter reputação pra tudo." Para que um hater qualquer, tipo que existe aos milhares na internet, não venha e apague, rasure e piche nossa página, já que ela é aberta ao publico.

Comment: Um hater pode ter uma grande reputação se ele quiser. Ele vai lá, ganha pontos e faz o que quiser depois

Comment: @Andylima "um hater **qualquer**" ênfase na parte importante. Temos *haters* aqui sim, mas aí tem outros meios de lidar com isso, fica mais raro acontecer e a pessoa tem algo a perder, um qualquer tem nada a perder.

Comment: Sua reclamação é especificamente sobre não ter conseguido responder uma pergunta, ou sobre [todas as funcionalidades que exigem reputação mínima](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges), e que vc acha que não deveriam ter? São duas discussões completamente diferentes.

Comment: Você possui duas perguntas sinalizadas, sendo uma delas fechada. Se estiver tentando respondê-las, o site não permitiria por estar sinalizada. Recomendo então que verifique e corrija a pergunta antes de poder respondê-la.

Comment: "Um hater pode ter uma grande reputação se ele quiser". Para ele chegar neste ponto, em algum momento ele ajudou a comunidade com algo, então ele simplesmente vai deixar sua contribuição e ser banido pelo seu único ou pouco mal comportamento. De qualquer forma a comunidade ainda sai ganhando.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Não é verdade que não pode responder sua própria pergunta porque não tem reputação, qualquer pessoa pode postar perguntas e respostas sem restrições, exceto se a pessoa já deu muitas perguntas ou respostas ruins e por isso há um bloqueio pelo sistema (esse bloqueio passa). No seu caso não consta nenhum bloqueio então pode responder sim.

Se não for isso precisa indicar com mais detalhes o que está acontecendo para vermos se dá para ajudar.

Ter reputação é necessário para selecionar quem pode fazer ações que terão consequência no site, então você ganha privilégios de acordo com o que mostra que tem algum comprometimento com o site. Não é perfeito mas é uma forma de controlar quem quer ajudar e quem quer atrapalhar, quem tem motivação e quem só quer sugar.

Comment: Eu fiz uma pergunta ontem e gostaria de respondê-la hoje, mas eu tentei responder e apareceu que eu deveria ter mais de 15 pontos de reputação. Ai eu apaguei a pergunta, pois se não tem reposta, não ajuda ninguém.

Comment: O engraçado é que essa publicação eu consigo, a outra eu não conseguia. Vou tentar recuperar minha antiga pergunta

Comment: Não, isso não ocorre, precisa de 15 pontos para poder votar em alguma coisa, não para responder, provavelmente clicou em lugar errado.

Comment: Eu recuperei a pergunta, mas ela não tem a opção "Responder à sua pergunta" mais. Antes tinha e estava inativo o botão

Comment: @Andylima qual a pergunta? Pode mandar um *print*  desta página?

Comment: Gostaria de mandar o print, mas no comentario não dá. No meu perfil só tem 3 perguntas. Esse problema é na pergunta mais recente.

Comment: Edite a pergunta e coloque lá.

Comment: Fiz uma nova e publiquei minha resposta junto

Comment: Fecharam de novo e perdi reputação, logo, voltei a fazer menos que nada por causa de reputação -.-'

Comment: @Andylima o código que meteu na pergunta sequer funciona?! A primeira consulta nunca é retornada, vai passar sempre em outros if depois.